# Tool to convert asp.net objects to javascript objects

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, intellisense

I'm working on a project where the backend is written using ASP.NET MVC 3 and the front end uses javascript to handle the frontend.  We use the `Json()` function of MVC 3 to pass objects to the front end using JSON.

I was wondering if there was a tool/IDE plugin that would provide intellisense for the frontend so that I can easily manipulate the objects in javascript.

For instance:

```
Namespace Models.ViewModels
<DataContract()>
Public Class LinkAdmin
    Inherits Base

    Private Property LinkAdminManager As New LinkAdminManager

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property Games As New List(Of Models.ViewModels.LinkAdminGame)

End Class
End Namespace
```

It would be uber convenient if, on the javascript side

```
myLinkAdmin.ga
```

would let me know that it was actually `Games`.

I've just made a bunch of typos on the javascript side and was hoping to avoid those in the future.

Pretty much, I'm looking for a tool that looks at an ASP.NET object and provides intellisense to javascript.  Does something like that exist?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Jquery then you can add the VSDoc to your page and get intellisense.  Maybe there is a VSDoc that you can add?

Comment: Nice idea. I'll see if someone knows of an automatic way to convert vb.net files over to VSDocs.